# Textarea has redundant spaces after binding with AngularJS model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs for making an SPA.

After clicking the OK button, my object will be serialized into a JSON string and be displayed inside a textarea control.

Here is my code:

- HTML :

  ```
  <div id="resultModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Result</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                      <textarea class="form-control"
                                readonly="readonly"
                                rows="10">
                          {{serializedInfo}}
                      </textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
          </div>

      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Part of my JS code:

  ```
  $scope.CreateFoodInfo = function (shownModal) {
                  $scope.serializedInfo = angular.toJson($scope.food);
                  $(shownModal).modal("show");
              }
  ```

But finally, I've got this :

[image: Redundant spaces after binding with AngularJs]

I got redundant spaces inside my textarea.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

I'm using

- JQuery 2.2.1
- AngularJs 1.5.0

Comment: Remove the whitespace inside the `<textarea>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra whitespace inside the textarea:

```
<textarea class="form-control"
    readonly="readonly"
    rows="10">{{serializedInfo}}</textarea>
```

With that said, you're probably better off with an `ng-model`

```
<textarea class="form-control"
        readonly="readonly"
        rows="10"
        ng-model="serializedInfo"></textarea>
```